# Monoidal closed structure(s) on the category "bicategories, with strict functors"?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

I'm working with globular operadic higher categories (with the Batanin/Leinster definitions) and ending up working a lot in the categories $P$-$\mathrm{Alg}$ of algebras for some globular operad $P$, together with (literal, strict, algebraic) morphisms between them.  A familiar case of these is $\textrm{Bicat}_\textit{str}$: the category of bicategories and strict functors between them.

It would be very handy if there were some kind of mapping space constructions in these categories --- that is, some reasonable monoidal closed structures on them.  Does anyone know what's been shown, either to exist or not to, either in the general case, or (more likely) for $\textrm{Bicat}_\textit{str}$?

(The most obvious specific candidate, of course, is Cartesian closure.  However, even $\textrm{Bicat}_\textit{str}$ fails to be Cartesian closed: chasing through the Yoneda argument that shows what a Cartesian closure would have to look like if it did exist leads one to a counterexample showing that the product doesn't preserve pushouts.  The next best hope would presumably be some sort of Gray tensor product; this is where I've not yet been able to find anything further on the closure question.)

Answer (score 2):

You may know this, but there are people thinking about this sort of question at least from the monoidal viewpoint.  For instance, there is [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4715), which shows that if you can defined what you want to mean by "a category enriched in P-Alg," then you can automatically recover from that a corresponding monoidal structure on P-Alg.  In particular, this can produce the Gray tensor product from the notion of Gray-category.  Although in general what you get is only a *lax* monoidal structure, and I don't think they have (yet) asked when it will be closed.

Comment: Thanks &mdash; yes, I have looked at that (though not in detail), but as you say it doesn't (iirc) start looking into the question of closure; and unfortunately, the mapping spaces are what I really want...